# Adding KML to vector layer from XML string

Tags: javascript, grails, openlayers

I have a XML string on a server. I need to have Open Layers get that, read it, and display it. It is connected to Grails. I know it is getting it because I have it alert me with the string. I tried this solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16629/how-to-add-kml-data-but-from-variable-not-from-url

but couldn't get it to display. I have no errors in my JS console.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check two things:

- `yourLayer.features` Does it contain something?
- If your layer contains features. Check that the `yourLayer.style` property is defined to a valid Style (meaning a Style instance that have renderers for the type of features). More on styling is OL [here](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html)